# Need to calculate the total cost BY year of each position

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking at the cost of each position from the perspective of total benefits and earnings amount to arrive at the benefit ratio for each employee at our company. I've determined the benefit rate by year for each position. This was formatted as:

[image]

I then created a new query and pivoted my fiscal year and benefit rate into columns data.
[image]

However I still have duplicate values of the position #. Ideally, I want distinct values for my position # field and for it to format as:

```
| Position# | Benefit Rate 2017 |Benefit Rate 2018 |
| 00001581   | 20.17% | 21.58%
| 00001852   | 35.00% | 40.50%
```

What is the best solution? Is this something I can do in PowerQuery or do I need to do Dax. Complicating things is that there are definetly null values in some Years because positions aren't always filled.

I created a new table using Distinct to isolate my Position #

Then I tried using LookupValue:

```
2018 = LookupValue('PositionNumberBenefitRateByYear'[2018],PositionNumberBenefitRateByYear[Employee Position.Position Number], 'Table'[Employee Position.Position Number])
```

Where PositionNumberBenefite by Year holds the values that I want to pull over and 'Table'[Employee Position.Position Number]) is the related value between each table.

But I get this error: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Comment: Don't pivot the data while importing it.  Instead, use a matrix table to display the data with year on columns.  This should summarize things the way you want

Comment: If you pivot your first table using power query, and there are no duplicate entries for a given number & year, the duplicate position #'s will not be present. If there are duplicates, you'll have to decide how you want to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code:

You need to do the actual work on PQ Editor: Here is the full M Code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bdBBDoUwCATQu3TdxQxtKZzFeP9r6Lf8qBE2LF5mEti2gnMISqlFIL+F2gQse/3j6BfSL2TT+UXBQuUjOYiVtKi1DGegtxuN/YU+9EaHPlGGe4IWCEtwnSLa8MU4RVQzZNTOnqAE2vmh/QA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Position Number" = _t, #"Fiscal Year" = _t, #"Benefit Ratio" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Fiscal Year", Int64.Type}, {"Benefit Ratio", type number}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Fiscal Year", type text}}, "tr-TR"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Fiscal Year", type text}}, "tr-TR")[#"Fiscal Year"]), "Fiscal Year", "Benefit Ratio", List.Sum),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"2022", "Benefit Rate 2022"}, {"2019", "Benefit Rate 2019"}, {"2020", "Benefit Rate 2020"}, {"2018", "Benefit Rate 2018"}, {"2017", "Benefit Rate 2017"}, {"2021", "Benefit Rate 2021"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

After making above listed steps of transformation, Your data should actually look like this:

[image: Data Transformation]

Then Go to Main Screen, Create a Table Visual, and then put columns into appropriate places. (Do not forget to format values to (%) percentage). If you do it, resulting screen will look like:

[image: Result Screen]

I hope This is what you are looking for!